# How to pass completion handler only after firebase fetching is completed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, closures, completionhandler

Currently I have a function which fetch chapter from Database.

```
func fetchChapters(completion: @escaping (_ chapters: [Chapter])->()) {
    var chapters: [Chapter] = []

    guard let novelID = novel?.nid else { return }
    handle = DataService.shared.chapterRef.child(novelID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
        guard let chapter = Chapter(snap: snap) else { return }
        chapters.append(chapter)
        print("chapter arr count", chapters.count)

        completion(chapters)

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

This function works fine but  what i want is that i want to call completion only after all chapter is downloaded from Database. Is there any way to achieve.

Comment: I would personally do this using delegation rather than using a completion handler, essentially there are callbacks for all parts of the process- the one you need relates to completion of the download. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate .

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question, but if you have some kind of a loop to download all chapters, then you can use DispatchGroup. This thing make possible to wait until some other methods will be finished. You can also use DispatchSemaphore. So if you need more info, please provide more code to see where is that place in your code all chapters become downloaded.